# Is it possible to link multiple .html pages in one offline web application (without being redirected to the browser)?

Tags: ipad, web, offline

I'm struggling at the moment with combining multiple .html pages in one offline web application. I worked with offline web applications for tablets before and know the basiscs of how to work with a .manifest file.

In this example I added all .html files to my main .mainfest file. The problem now is, that when I save my application for offline use on an iPad and click on a link to one of the other .html files, safari opens to show the linked page.

My question now is, if it would be possible to link pages together in one offline web app or if it is necessary to unite every item I wish to display in one single-paged solution.

Best regards,
ik

Answer (score 0):

You can always edit your hrefs to link to the local file instead of the remote file!

Comment: I only used relative links, is there anything more I can do?

<a class="btn" href="page.html"><img src="img.png"/></a>

Comment: Can you edit your post to include one of the pages you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just Safari popping out of 'web app mode' then, depending on your situation, the best solution might be to use a third-party app like [HTML Presenter](http://bit.ly/html-presenter) or others to present your web app offline (or else, to create the single-page version you described as a possibility).

With HTML Presenter you don't need a manifest but you have to package the app as a zip file to distribute it (via email or it syncs with Dropbox or SFTP). Because of its distribution mechanism and cost ($5) it's probably not a solution if you intend on broad distribution, but might work if the users are a defined team.

We basically wrote the app to solve this problem for ourselves, and our sales team use it to show the web apps we make ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags automatically open the linked page on safari. But you can override that with javascript.
The following code opens nextpage.htm inside the webapp:

```
window.location = "nextpage.htm"
```

You can make a for loop to search for each `<a>` element and bind the code to its `onClick` event. Don't forget to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag by returning false.